# Less Annoying CRM integration with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crm

I have searched google and also reached out to the developers of Less Annoying CRM and was told the integration code for LACRM api should work on ASP.NET as it was designed for PHP, but it is the same concept. They didn't provide any workaround.

My Intention:
I want a form submit from  `<div class="form-field-wrapper half left margin-top-1"><input name="name" type="text" asp-for="@Model.booking.Name" placeholder="Name" data-val="true" required="required"><ValidationMessage For="@Model.booking.Name" /></div>` to go into the LACRM system so I will be able to see and organised those contacts in the right places and to the assigned persons in my organisation.
The Less Annoying CRM API code is:

```
 
$UserCode = "ABCDE";

$APIToken = "111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111";

$Function = "CreateContact";
 
$Parameters = array(
    "FullName"=-->$_REQUEST['ContactName'],
    "Email"=>array(
                0=>array(
                    "Text"=>"$_REQUEST[Email]",
                    "Type"=>"Work"
                )
            ),
    "Phone"=>array(
                0=>array(
                    "Text"=>"$_REQUEST[Phone]",
                    "Type"=>"Work"
                )
            ),
);
 
$Result = CallAPI($UserCode, $APIToken, $Function, $Parameters);
$ContactId = $Result['ContactId'];
  
$Function = "CreateNote";
$Parameters = array(
    "ContactId"=>$ContactId,
    "Note"=>$_REQUEST['Comment']
);
 
$Result = CallAPI($UserCode, $APIToken, $Function, $Parameters);
 
header('location:confirm.html');
   
function CallAPI($UserCode, $APIToken, $Function, $Parameters){
    $APIResult = file_get_contents("https://api.lessannoyingcrm.com?UserCode=$UserCode&APIToken=$APIToken&".
                "Function=$Function&Parameters=".urlencode(json_encode($Parameters)));
    $APIResult = json_decode($APIResult, true);
      
    if(@$APIResult['Success'] === true){
        //echo "Success!";
    }
    else{
        echo "API call failed. Error:".@$APIResult['Error'];
        exit;
    }
    return $APIResult;
}
`


Are there ways to get this to work in ASP.NET MVC? 
I appreciate all the suggestions in advance.
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: The question here is how to take an Api to make a http request for asp.net Mvc. The api as I am told can work in any language but it was designed for php specifically. How do I integrate this in the asp.net environment